# How capture image from video stream work ?

Tags: video, video-streaming

From what i know - video stream is steam of byte array and **it is not** stream of images that by moving forward the images we will have a video play. 
Also, each image ( frame ) is base on the image before ( in case the scene is not change ).

1. is it right or i missing something ?
2. in case i'm right - how can we produce image collection of all the captured images that was played on the video ? - i mean how can we capture all the frame in real time without save the image before.

Thanks

Comment: not all frames are based on the previous just most.  Generally every 2-4 seconds a baseline frame (I-Frame) is sent.

Comment: thanks, is there is some good site to learn it ? can you please explain more ?

Comment: The format I'm most familiar with is `H.264` (though there are others). You can google that, or whatever the format you are streaming.  There is too much to the spec to post here.